# Duplicate bridge mislead

Tags: bridge

If player pulls card out of his hand and then puts it back in his hand, and opponents have seen the card, must player play that card?

Comment: Not sure if relevant but ACBL? Or Europe/elsewhere? There are duplicate bridge laws which might potentially vary with (large) jurisdiction.

Comment: @Aryabhata: My understanding is that the Laws of Duplicate Bridge are promulgated by, and authorized by, the World Bridge Federation; albeit with assistance and co-operation from from the A.C.B.L., E.B.L., and Portland Club. Only where specifically designated in the Laws are authorities delegated to National and Organizing committees.

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere: That makes sense. Hopefully this one is a global rule.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant rule is Law 45 (C) from the [Laws of Duplicate Bridge (2017)](http://www.worldbridge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2017LawsofDuplicateBridge-paginated.pdf)

> **LAW 45 - CARD PLAYED**
>
> ...
>
> *C. Card Deemed to be Played*
>
> 1. A defender’s card held so that it is possible for his partner to see its face is deemed played
>      to the current trick (if the defender has already made a legal play to the current trick, see
>      Law 45E).
> 2. Declarer is deemed to have played a card from his hand if it is:
>      (a) held face up, touching or nearly touching the table; or
>      (b) maintained in such a position as to indicate that it has been played.
> 3. A card in the dummy is played if it has been deliberately touched by declarer except for the
>      purpose either of arranging dummy’s cards, or of reaching a card above or below the card
>      or cards touched.
> 4. (a) A card is played if a player names or otherwise designates it as the card he proposes to
>      play (but see Law 47).
>      (b) Declarer may correct an unintended designation of a card from dummy until he next
>      plays a card from either his own hand or from dummy. A change of designation may be
>      allowed after a slip of the tongue, but not after a loss of concentration or a
>      reconsideration of action. If an opponent has, in turn, played a card that was legal before
>      the change in designation, that opponent may withdraw the card so played, return it to
>      his hand, and substitute another (see Laws 47D and 16C1).

So to answer your question: No, a Defender's card is not played simply because an opponent (Declarer) can see which card it is; rather it is played if it is held so that the Defender's partner can identify it,

Further clarification through Minutes of the W.B.F. Laws Committee, where necessary, are available [here](http://www.worldbridge.org/rules-regulations/2017-laws-of-duplicate-bridge/).